# Can't run makefile, Nothing to be done for `Makefile_JulianaMarquez_S6C2_EDO_CASA.mk'

Tags: makefile

So I need to write a makefile to compile and execute two scripts that generate some graphs. The two scripts work perfectly when I call them separately from the terminal, but the makefile shows the error "Nothing to be done for `Makefile_JulianaMarquez_S6C2_EDO_CASA.mk'."

My makefile code:

```
all :: graficas

graficas :: solucionEDO.png errorEuler.png errorRunge.png

solucionEDO.png :: Plots_JulianaMarquez_S6C2_EDO_CASA.py DatosED.dat

python3 Plots_JulianaMarquez_S6C2_EDO_CASA.py

errorEuler.png :: Plots_JulianaMarquez_S6C2_EDO_CASA.py DatosED.dat
    python3 Plots_JulianaMarquez_S6C2_EDO_CASA.py

errorRunge.png :: Plots_JulianaMarquez_S6C2_EDO_CASA.py DatosED.dat
    python3 Plots_JulianaMarquez_S6C2_EDO_CASA.py

DatosED.dat :: JulianaMarquez_S6C2_EDO_CASA.exe
    ./JulianaMarquez_S6C2_EDO_CASA.exe

JulianaMarquez_S6C2_EDO_CASA.exe :: JulianaMarquez_S6C2_EDO_CASA.cpp
    g++ -lm JulianaMarquez_S6C2_EDO_CASA.cpp -o JulianaMarquez_S6C2_EDO_CASA.exe

clean :
    rm -rf *png graficas
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm calling the .mk file as

```
make Makefile_JulianaMarquez_S6C2_EDO_CASA.mk
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
make Makefile_JulianaMarquez_S6C2_EDO_CASA.mk
```

The arguments to the make program tell it to build that target.  The above command asks make "please build the target `Makefile_JulianaMarquez_S6C2_EDO_CASA.mk`".  Make will oblige, see that that file already exists and that there are no recipes available on how to update it, so it says "nothing to be done".  And it's right.

If you want to tell make what makefile to use, use the `-f` option:

```
make -f Makefile_JulianaMarquez_S6C2_EDO_CASA.mk
```

See the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefile-Arguments.html#index-_002d_002dfile-1), or run `man make` to see the command line syntax for make.